# ConTeXt: arbitrary Unicode code point

Tags: context, unicode, context-mkiv

How to print a glyph by Unicode code point? i.e. what is the ConTeXt equivalent of the following LaTeX (displaying a capital Alpha):

```
\symbol{"0391} % hex
\symbol{913}   % dec
\symbol{'1621} % oct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works in plain TeX, thus also in ConTeXt:

```
  \char"0391 % hex
  \char913   % dec
  \char'1621 % oct
```